# How to use aggregation on nested object in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to the elastic search and trying to form queries. I am facing some problem in extracting information from the elastic storage. Below, I am trying to do the groupby in the elastic search query..

Lets say I have the below data :

```
[{

    "a" : {
        "b" : "xxx",
        "c" : "yyy"
    },
    "l" : {
        "m" : "zzz",
        "n" : "sss"
    }
},
{

    "a" : {
        "b" : "xxx",
        "c" : "qqq"
    },
    "l" : {
        "m" : "ttt",
        "n" : "jjj"
    }
}
]
```

I would like to display all the rows who has the value "xxx" for key "b" in object "a".

In the above I have two rows that match my need. So I would to like to display the above two. This means its a "group by a.b"

How shall I achieve this elastic search query? As the key I am looking to group by is the nested key, I am having trouble forming the query.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

What I am looking for is not just if "a.b" key has value "xxx". I want to do a group by. So if there is are two records under "a.b" with value "xxx" and another two records under "a.b" with value "kkk", I would like to see them as two groups.

Which is like in this case, two json objects should be the result, each containing their specific group results.

something like below:

```
{
{
    {    
        "a" : {
            "b" : "xxx",
            "c" : "yyy"
        },
        "l" : {
            "m" : "zzz",
            "n" : "sss"
        }
    },
    {
        "a" : {
            "b" : "xxx",
            "c" : "qqq"
        },
        "l" : {
            "m" : "ttt",
            "n" : "jjj"
        }
    }
},
{
    {    
        "a" : {
            "b" : "kkk",
            "c" : "..."
        },
        "l" : {
            "m" : "___",
            "n" : "---"
        }
    },
    {
        "a" : {
            "b" : "kkk",
            "c" : "..."
        },
        "l" : {
            "m" : "___",
            "n" : "---"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does your mapping look like? Would these next level be of type `nested` or simply `inner objects`?

Comment: They are just string values.. not a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done.

My aggregation chain is of the below order

[Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) -> [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) -> [Reverse Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) -> [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

The arrows are all indicator of sub-aggregations.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "nesting":{  
         "nested":{  
            "path":"a"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "grouping_by":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"a.b"
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "parent_docs":{  
                     "reverse_nested":{  

                     },
                     "aggs":{  
                        "mydocs":{  
                           "top_hits":{  
                              "size":10
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This would allow you to perform `groupby` as what your expect. Also note that I'm assuming that the field `b` is of type keyword.

Also note `Top Hits` only shows the top 10 documents, you can increase the number if you wish to see all the documents.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I do not think it works. We need an aggregation here. I am looking for a groupBy with nested object key.

Below is my query which is returning everything but I am still trying on how I can use aggregations on nested key. We need to use "aggs"

Comment: Sorry but I have edited my question for better understanding. I wanted to do the group by on a nested field. Which gives their specific result-sets. Not looking to retrieve the result based on one value ("xxx").

Please check "EDIT 1" section in my comment.

Comment: @Deepak could you check it now once again? The results are not closely matching to the format you are looking for, but I've been able to group based on `values` of `a.b` Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You need a "nested" key in the query which is missing. Your query is giving all the available records as such with no grouping.

Comment: @Deepak I've updated my answer once again. Apologies for pushing it long. I've pinged you on chat, if this is not the solution, can you join the chat room.